# How to create a ref to child component, store it in context and pass it to a sibling in React with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, scroll-lock

I have a component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogTitle, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const FormDialog = ({ formId, onClose, onSubmit }: Props) => (
  <Dialog open disableBackdropClick>
    <DialogTitle>
      Create New Form
      <br />
      <Typography
        color="textSecondary"
        variant="caption"
      >
        Start a new form by filling in some starter info.
      </Typography>
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent dividers>
      <FormContainer
        formId={formId}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        onClose={onClose}
      />
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
);

export default FormDialog;
```

In a deeply nested component further down the line, I want to lock scrolling on this `Dialog` when a `Popper` (using Material UI Popper not popper.js) is open. I was able to do this with the vanilla DOM API, and found that the component I need a reference to is `DialogContent`. (The `wheel` event isn't bubbling up to `Dialog`).

How do I create a `ref` pointing to `DialogContent` and send it as a `Context.Provider` value over `FormContainer`?

Open to threading it as a prop too, but guessing if one is possible so is the other?

I looked into `forwardRef` and it doesn't seem like that would make sense here, but I could also be getting discouraged by Typescript. I was also thinking about `useRef(null)` inside the component, passing the variable output as a `ref` prop to `DialogContent`, catching `ref.current` in a `useEffect`, saving it with `useState`, and passing it to `FormContainer` but don't know if that would work / hoping that is not the solution!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you showed where and how you have implemented Popper, but i hope this gives you some ideas:

Create a context and wrap all `FormDialog` children inside it.

Then create a state in `FormDialog`, that points to the status of the popper.

Pass both state, and setState functions down to wherever the Popper is located.

**FormDialog**

```
const FormDialogContext=createContext(null)

const FormDialog = ({ formId, onClose, onSubmit }: Props) => (

  const [isPopperOpen,setPopperOpen]=useState(false)

  <FormDialogContext.Provider value={[isPopperOpen,setPopperOpen]}>
   <Dialog open disableBackdropClick>
    <DialogTitle>
      Create New Form
      <br />
      <Typography
        color="textSecondary"
        variant="caption"
      >
        Start a new form by filling in some starter info.
      </Typography>
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent dividers>
      <FormContainer
        formId={formId}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        onClose={onClose}
      />
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
</FormDialogContext.Provider>
);

export default FormDialog;
```

Now, in any component where your Popper is located

```
 const [isPopperOpen,setPopperOpen]=useContext(FormDialogContext)

return (<>
         <Button 
          onClick={()=>setPopperOpen(prevState=>!prevState)}>
          Toggle Popper
          </Button>
          <Popper 
          open={isPopperOpen}
         ..................
```

Now  you have total control over the status of Popper within `FormDialog`

Comment: Thank you! So it's the other way around, I want to control the `FormDialog` from the `Popper` by disabling its scrolling. I was looking for a solution to do this that wouldn't involve calling up through callbacks because there can be multiple poppers and I wanted the functionality in a hook.